# Wake up a thread after a specific time

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have two threads, say 1 and 2, and have put 2 to sleep. 1 performs some task and sets a timer to wake up 2 't' seconds after the task is done.

So, I need to program to send a signal to 2 't' seconds later.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: use condition variable. What framework are you using?

Comment: Why not send the signal to thread 2 immediately after the task and have that thread wait 't' seconds before reacting to the signal?

Comment: The 't' second wait is necessary. Also, thread 1 does not exist until 2 awakes ( after 't' seconds )

Comment: How did you "*put 2 to sleep*"?

Comment: @alk that is also something I need to know. How do I make a pthread sleep indefinitely?

Comment: `The 't' second wait is necessary` Ok, I suggested that you do the wait in thread 2.

Comment: Use a condition variable. I would make thread 1 wake thread 2 immediately, then have thread 2 put itself to sleep for t seconds. Otherwise thread 1 is blocked for those t seconds.

Comment: Either use thread-specific mechanics like mutexes and conditions, or use POSIX tools like `pause` and `(pthread)kill()`.

Comment: I would like to reword myself - the 't' second wait before thread 2 wakes up and it is necessary. I cannot wakeup thread 2 and then wait for t seconds.

Comment: In that case you need to wait in thread 1 or create a third thread. I don't see *why* you couldn't wait in thread 2 though.

Comment: advantage of timed condition over sleep: if you need to terminate the thread or continue execution before the time expires, you can signal it to cleanly unblock your thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timed-wait on a condition variable, which will wake up when that time is reached / has elapsed. You can also just make a thread sleep for a period of time.

pthreads (which you specify) only has a wait until an absolute time.

The new standard C++ library and boost give you the option of `wait_for(time_period)` or `wait_until(absolute_time)`.

In your case I don't think you need to do any of this but you might use a 3rd thread.

1. Thread 1 performs the task, Thread 2 waits on a condition variable, when thread 1 completes the task it creates a 3rd thread which sleeps and wakes thread 2.
2. Thread 1 performs the task and immediately signals the condition variable held by thread 2, but thread 2 then sleeps before it continues. (So really it wakes up earlier but it simulates the delay).  No need for a 3rd thread, However thread 2 might be a "client" thread and you want to enforce the delay so use method 1 if that is the case.

Comment: You can do away with the third thread if thread 2 is woken immediately when the task completes and then puts itself back to sleep with a timeout.

Comment: Yes that is method 2 but if thread 2 is held by a client and you want to force them to get the delay you'd use method 1.

Comment: Oh yes, so it is ... was the answer edited or did I just not read to the end?! :-)

Comment: I edited the answer very quickly but your comment was after my edit so I guess you didn't look properly

Answer (score 0):

Prior than C++11, the standard library did not offer timers. Even with C++11, you have standrd timing facilities (e.g., sleep, condition variables, etc.) but you have to assemble them to have the desired behavior.

So, you roughly have the following otions:

- rely on some specific (cross-platform) library (e.g., Qt, Boost, etc.)
- rely on OS-level facilities (e.g., Posix on Linux)
- create a third thread acting as timer: once activated, it sleeps for 2 seconds and then signals the second thread through a condition variable
- let the first thread compute the amount of time to wait after the work done, make it sleep and then signal the other thread through a condition variable

I suggest the last option.

Comment: The standard library has timers for making threads sleep, waiting on mutexes, waiting on condition variables and waiting on futures.

Comment: I did not understand the last option, could you elaborate? - Like how can you signal the second thread after the first has slept? I want to set a timer to send the signal from the first thread